# Python, counting repeated name

Tags: python

```
def name_counts(alist):
    split = []
    for listitem in alist:
        split.extend(listitem.split())
    dicti = {}
    for word in split:
        if word in dicti:
            dicti[word] +=1
        else:
            dicti[word] = 0
    print(split)
    return dicti


name_list = ["David Joyner", "David Zuber", "Brenton Joyner",
             "Brenton Zuber", "Nicol Barthel", "Shelba Barthel",
             "Shelba Crowley", "Shelba Fernald", "Shelba Odle",
             "Shelba Fry", "Maren Fry"]
print(name_counts(name_list))
```

This function should return dictionary `dicti` where key is name / lastname from the list `list`and value of the key is the number of times the name or lastname repeats in that list.

```
def name_counts(alist):
        split = []
        for listitem in alist:
            split.extend(listitem.split())
```

This part of code converts the `alist` which has the value of `name_list` to a list where each name and lastname are separate values in the list. This list with names and last name separated is called `split`. When i check the code at this point, It works, it prints the `split` and i t has all the names and lastnames separated.

The problem is that the following code doesn't count the repeating names or lastnames correctly, function still runs but the amount of times the names and last names appear in the list `split` is incorrect.

The problem is in this part of code:

```
dicti = {}
    for word in split:
        if word in dicti:
            dicti[word] +=1
        else:
            dicti[word] = 0
```

Help

Comment: This question would be better (easier to answer and more likely to get upvoted/less likely to get downvoted) if it  explicitly showed the expected output, the actual output, and how they differ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counts are off by 1, because the first time you see the name, you initialize that name's count to 0.  If you're going to keep the current flow-control structure, you should initialize the count to 1 at that point instead of 0.

But here's a more compact version that avoids luring you into that mistake:

```
def name_counts(alist):
    split = [name for listitem in alist for name in listitem.split()]
    return {name : split.count(name) for name in set(split)}
```

Note the use of `set(split)` to give you the set of *unique* names, over which you then iterate to do the counting.

And actually, there's also an off-the-peg counting dictionary, called `Counter`, in Python's standard library:

```
import collections
def name_counts(alist):
    return collections.Counter(name for listitem in alist for name in listitem.split())
```

Comment: If this is all it is (_and I believe it is_), OP really should of mentioned that this is all there problem was rather than have us figure it out. Rather than just saying it's incorrect.

Comment: thanks. first paragraph helped.
but how is this notation called, how can i search google for it - `name for listitem in alist` ?
i havent encountered this in my course, all ive seen is - `for x in y`, nothing ever came before `for`

Comment: @Caribbean One or more `for` loops inside square brackets is called a "list comprehension".  It is one of the most powerful and convenient programming primitives in Python, or indeed any language in my opinion.  Closely related are the "dict comprehension" (same thing but in curly braces, as in my first listing) and the "generator expression" (same thing but in round parentheses, as in my second listing).   One of the coolest things about them is that you can also include conditional expressions in them to filter the outcome.  Look 'em up, and never look back.